# Resize partitions Meizu MX4 Ubuntu edition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, meizu-mx4

I've a Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Edition. Is it possible to resize partitions?
I've already installed gparted, but i can't start gparted:

```
$ sudo gparted
Failed to get D-Bus connection: operation not permitted
Too few arguments.

(gpartedbin:5134): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
Too few arguments
```

Which arguments do I need to start gparted?

Comment: These are 2 separate questions / problems: gparted GUI doesn't work as it has no front-end for Unity display server and there is no X server on ubuntu-phone. Resizing a partition of a mounted file system (i.e. directly from booted ubuntu phone) might be difficult or impossible as mounted ext4 can only be extended (not moved, not shrinked).

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because  the volume you gotta shrink or expand is the one u are using ( is mounted ) you better use a Live distro in order to do so....sysresccd ( http://www.sysresccd.org/)

basically make a live usb of that distro ....and u will be able to modify 
your partition ....keep in mind that u can't edit mounted partitions
and u can't un-mount partitions being used by the sys op you running.

Comment: Thanks, but the Meizu MX4 is a phone, I think i can't start a phone using a live distro. I've found a post at xda-developers, maybe that's an option. I guess a partition is not used while flashing an image http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=61773305&postcount=2

Comment: if your phone is rooted you got several options apart from start a live distribution , did u know clockwork app?

Comment: The phone is unlocked by default.